# How do you get the editor ID from within a PySpark Jupyter notebook running on an EMR cluster?

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

In an effort to keep my code modular, I have Jupyter notebooks calling other notebooks. Unfortunately, I've had to hard-code the editor ID (for example, `e-BKTM2DIHXBEDRU44ANWRKIU8N`) into my notebook. Is there a way to load this dynamically?